# Is there a 3D modeller that Auto-generates models from blueprints?

Tags: 3d, automation, modeling

Could there be a 3D modeller that can generate a 3D model from a blueprint or reference image where the blueprint shows at least two different perspectives of the object, so the modeller uses some technique like starting with a rough shaped mesh and projecting the blueprint background co-ordinated to 3d co-ordinates and shaping the mesh to the blueprint shape like a dough ? Or starting with a flat shape and extruding while shaping it to the blueprint's shape? 
 I could have created a Blender script for this if I had time.

Comment: It is common for people to use blueprints or reference images as a guide to get proportions right as they model or sculpt, but don't expect that to be automated. [Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) is the process of taking multiple photos from different angles to generate a 3d model, it needs more than three views from a blueprint.

Comment: First of all, this question seem a bit off topic here. — Maybe you've seen this, since it is shared online every now and then, but this a pretty solid real world example of photogrammetry https://youtu.be/eXMJr-aB4qw I thought I'd share it since it's pretty cool. — What you are asking about is too much. I definitely don't know anything about this, but I feel like you need like an AI to do what you want. AI assisted design does exist but this seems a bit too much. You may have to invest millions to Autodesk to pursue this further.

Comment: Yes... AutoCad (or other CAD programs)... But you need to draw the blueprint and the orthogonal view on... Autocad (or other CAD programs)

Comment: But also you are confusing Blueprints to perspectives.

Comment: Or do you want an AI driven modeler, so advanced that could see a sketch on a napkin and a perspective from the other side? Even humans struggle with that. When we get there... we are in trouble.

Comment: How to do it in AutoCad?  To answer your second question, like I mentioned in my question, no I need only a system with a simple algorithm that reads the lines on the blueprint and converts the 2d co-ordinates of those lines into 3d space, creating a rough shape from the blueprint either by extrusion or a premade mesh, then the human modeler fine tunes the mesh.

Comment: Yes there exsist such tools

Comment: If you want an idea of how hard it is to go from a photo to a 3D model, check [this](https://github.com/Amir-Arsalan/Synthesize3DviaDepthOrSil) out

Answer (score 2):

I myself do ***exactly*** this sort of thing for clients as an architectural designer, 3D modeler and renderer quite quickly and efficiently, in a toolset I've developed over the years (using either [**ArchiCAD**](http://www.graphisoft.com/archicad/) or [**modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) depending upon client and project needs) but based on the ***huge*** *variability* of plans I see, I'd ***really*** have trouble imagining a fully-automated process or tool that would have the range of responses necessary to work in the real-world... even within a single firm, there tends to be a **lot** of deviation from the firm's published CAD or BIM standards, and though many US firms will *tell* you they use or follow the [**National CAD Standards**](https://www.nationalcadstandard.org/ncs6/) very *few* do in fact *follow* them - it'd be more true to say they use them as a baseline for their own adapted version specific to their client-base, use-case and project mix.

As a result, if you wrote a scripted system to derive walls from lines of type X on layer Y - it'd fail in 80% of files imported.

I use the client-provided CAD as a reference and snapping base - and if I only get scanned images of the plans, I can effectively do the same.